# How to find the maximum value based on another column?

Tags: excel

I am trying to find the maximum value based on another column. This is what I have tried.

```
=MAX(IF(Sheet3!$B$2:$B$5491=Sheet4!A3,Sheet3!$E$2:$E$5491))
```

How I am reading this code is that if the criteria in sheet 3 in column B is equivalent to the cell in A3 in sheet 4, then return the maximum value that would be in column E from sheet 3. I found this code online and have tried variations but all it is doing is returning 0. Is there another way I could go about finding the max value?

Thanks,

GCC

Comment: Your array formula needs to be confirmed with CONTROL+SHIFT+ENTER, not just ENTER.  If done correctly, Excel will automatically place curly braces around the formula.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an **Array formula** (aka *CSE formula*). After entering or editing it, you should press

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

otherwise it won't work. Always remember this for array formulas.

Comment: I still get 0. any reason you can think of why?

Comment: @GCC The formula is correct. It could be that the criteria was not found. Possible reasons is when comparing texts to numbers.